# How to handle label as a variable populated with sql query

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I might be asking this all wrong and I will try my best to explain my question here. I have a query that populates a number of different GUI features. One of them being a label.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (row["NT"].ToString() == "C")
    {
        conSpell.Text = row["full_name_nd_ro"].ToString();
    }
}
```

I am able to get the value from the query into the label...Except, when there is no value in the query, the label remains populated with the old value on multiple executions.

I'm not really sure how to approach this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any logic that clears the label out.

Just add this code to clear the label:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    conSpell.Text = string.Empty;

foreach( ... your code )
```